# DAX magic or new cube?

Tags: dax, ssas, cube, azure-analysis-services, analysisservices

Is there a way to check from DAX, which Power BI report a user is opening?

My problem is that I have a model with tables:

-**Revenue**.

-**CostCenter**.

I have RLS set up for two special users: I take their USERNAME(), and I give these 2 users access to a specific set of **Cost Centers**.

Now, I am creating a new PowerBI, I am trying to reutilize the same cube.

But, the access is based on another table named ‘**Contract**’, so these same two users shall have special access to a set of **contracts**.

Can I have a way of using 2 Power BIs, pointing to the same cube, and in one report they shall see **CostCenters** x,y,z and in the other **Contracts** a, b, c?

Or is it more convenient to just “copy paste” the entire cube (that is, have 2 different cubes) and do the RLS on each one. (I am also in doubt what is the preferred way in terms of maintenance).

Comment: Yes so you can either deploy the same cube twice and have them with different roles (one for each RLS) or you can use a composite model approach and add the roles on the composite model from each PBI file.

Comment: You can easily achieve that by using one cube. You need to have a User table with UserName, CostCenter & Contract field and join this table with  CostCenter and Contracts table.